# A word for someone asking too many questions..?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm typing an email, well my 3rd to the same person, where I've been asking one question after another instead of putting all of them in a single email. I'm very much entitled to ask questions and the other person (not a team, an individual) is obligated to answer them. But I just want to be polite this time and say, "I don't want to be a ____ but there is this other question" or something to that effect. Help?

PS: It is not that I'm asking a question on top of the previous' response, I just think of a new question to ask in the same context.

Comment: "Pest" is the word.  And if you do this habitually, even if you are entitled to do so, eventually someone is going to get really pissed.

Comment: "I'm sorry for [being a **nuisance**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nuisance)..." But if you are on very friendly terms you can get away with: *Sorry for being a [pain in the ass](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pain+in+the+ass), but I've got another question to ask:...."

Comment: "I am sorry for bothering you again..." will be nice and polite.

Comment: I think I'll go with nuisance. But being new to this specific SE forum, why is my question downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Pest*** is the word I immediately thought of, but it is probably too strong.  Pest is defined by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pest) as:

> 1. an annoying or troublesome person, animal, or thing; nuisance.
> 2. an insect or other small animal that harms or destroys garden plants, trees, etc.
> 3. a deadly epidemic disease, especially a plague; pestilence

I suspect Defintion #1 was derived from one of the other two, probably #3 --pestilence -- but I would need to do the research to be sure.

***nuisance*** is a better word for your situation.  From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nuisance)

> a person, thing, or situation that is annoying or that causes trouble
>   or problems

Two example sentences from Merriam-Webster:

> the new neighbor is threatening to become a nuisance, dropping in on
>   us several times a day
>
> folding up this map correctly is such a nuisance

**Pest** is a stronger word than **nuisance**.  I suggest you use **nuisance** or the phrase suggested by @Rathony ***"I'm sorry for bothering you again".***